# changing brightness using serial comm of 3 leds

Tags: arduino

So far I have wrote code so that if 1 then enter pressed or send clicked, and then 1 again and enter pressed or send clicked causes LED one to turn on, if ‘1’ ‘0’ is entered in a similar way then LED 1 turns off, and so on for LEDs two and three, ie: ‘2’ ‘1’ turns on LED 2, ‘3’ ’0’ turns off LED 3.

```
 int incomingVal;
    int ledPin = 16; 
    int ledPin2 = 15; 
    int ledPin3 = 14; 

    void setup()
    {

      Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
      Serial.println("starting");
      pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ledPin2,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ledPin3,OUTPUT);
    }




    void loop()
    {
      if (Serial.available() > 0 ) //then chars are in the serial buffer
      {
        incomingVal = Serial.parseInt();
        Serial.print("You entered: ");
        Serial.println(incomingVal);

        if (incomingVal == 10)//turns off led 1 
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  

        }

         if (incomingVal == 11)//turns on led 1 
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  

        }

         if (incomingVal == 20)//turns off led 2
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);  

        }

         if (incomingVal == 21)//turns on led 2
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);  

        }

         if (incomingVal == 30)//turns off led 3
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);  

        }

         if (incomingVal == 31)//turns on led 3
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);  

        }

      }

    }
```

How could i change the code so i can enter a third value to change the brightness from 0 to 250? For example, typing “2,1,125” would make LED 2 to light up at 50% brightness.

Answer (score 1):

To make the LED light up at half brightness you need to use [pulse width modulation](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM). Make sure that the pins you are using have ~ next to them (pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11 on the Uno).

I would change your input method slightly, because 0 brightness is essentially the same as turning the LED off, you should only need 2 numbers. The first number corresponds to the LED, the second number corresponds to the brightness.

```
int led_pins[3] = {9,10,11};

int incomingVal;
int brightness;
int parsed_value;
int x = 0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Serial.println("starting");
  pinMode(led_pins[0],OUTPUT);  // You could also use a loop here
  pinMode(led_pins[1],OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_pins[2],OUTPUT);
}




void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0 ) //then chars are in the serial buffer
  {
    incomingVal = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.print("You entered: ");
    Serial.println(incomingVal);

    //figure out which LED we selected
    parsed_value = incomingVal;
    while (parsed_value > 9){
      /*
      because of integer division, this line will remove the last
       number from the integer. ie 11 / 10 = 1 (the result is rounded down)
       The loop will continue until only 1 digit remains
       */
      x++;
      parsed_value = parsed_value / 10; 
    }
    // x represents the number of times parsed_value was divided by 10
    // this line removes the first digit of the incoming value, leaving
    // the brightness
    brightness = incomingVal - pow(10,x)*parsed_value;
    /*parsed_value will be 1 greater than the array key value because
     the array is 0 based.*/
    //set the LED to the right brightness
    analogWrite(led_pins[parsed_value-1],brightness);
  }

}
```